# Does script tag create new execution context?

Tags: javascript

When we load external script does this script (aka module) create new execution context? 

**My index html file.**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**My app.js file**

```
function test() {
    debugger;
}

test();
```

In bellow screen shot call stack status when inside test function. Is this anonymous reflection of my app.js file's Execution Context?

[image]

Comment: One word answer NO. For ex. if you load jQuery and try to access it in some other file it is available. But yes scopes is something you need to understand.

Comment: @Manish Yeah I know  my declared variable inside other file accesible in Global Scope. But this is interesting me where come to this anonymous call stack? And when I read other blogs in every blog say call stack bottom execution context is Global Execution Context. Then this is meaning anoymous represent Global?

Comment: I ask this question because I came here from reason to we can load 2 other script file and if one throw error this is not make problem to load other script

Comment: In this case when you load two files and lets say the first one throws error while loading/executing anonymous piece of code then this will cause issues you need to be careful about such case as they will break you website.

Comment: But this is not make problem to load other script